# mysqli select from two tables with one of them have multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql

```
<?php
select1($conn); 
function select2 ($conn,$id ,$name)
{   
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT def FROM define WHERE wordkey = ?");
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $id);
   $stmt->execute(); 
   $stmt->bind_result($def);
     while($stmt->fetch()) {
     echo "here"; // for testing
     $wordArray += $def; 
     //I will make a call to the js function here sending id, name and wordArray
    }  
//$stmt->close();
}
function select1 ($conn){
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT id , name FROM words");
   $stmt2->execute(); 
   $stmt2->bind_result($id, $name);
    while($stmt2->fetch()) {
     select2 ($conn,$id ,$name);
}
 }
?>
```

I want to ask question I have words table and def table. in def table i have multiple definitions for the same words.id. Is it possible to select them in one query statement ? 
words table have id , name 
def table have id, wordkey , definition

I want to retrieve name and for each name select all its definitions so that I will then call a javascript function (id, name, defArray)
to display each name with the array of its definitions.
I thought of doing it through 2 select statement, but the problem is the select2 function is not working.

Comment: Can you provide detail of your tables, fields etc, and give an example of what you have tried?

Comment: It certainly is. Well, it is if the definitions table has a column that references a word in the words table.

Comment: This seems to just be a mysql question. Are you having issues with creating the query or using it in PHP?

Comment: yes, it is possible, just join both tables on proper key

Answer (score 0):

As I can assume from the very limited details from your question.

Try

```
select a.name, b.definition from words a, def b where a.id=b.word_id
```

In the above query we are simply accessing the data from multiple tables.

Please supply some more explanation (possibly with code) for precise bug fixings.

Hope it helps, All the best!

Comment: kindly check my edited question. I thought I should use 2 select statements

Comment: You can use the query above and use one a.id field also. Then you may process the whole records in a loop where you can arrange it in your way. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following:

**words**
ID | Word

**definitions**
ID | WordID | Definition

```
SELECT D.Definition AS definition, W.Word AS word 
FROM definitions D, words W 
WHERE W.ID = D.WordID 
ORDER BY W.Word ASC
```

This will display rows of definitions, ordered by the word they correspond to.

Comment: I think that will not apply for what I need. Kindly check my edited question